# t-sql query that returns missing records

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join, missing-data

I have a query (ContactFormTypesRequired) that returns ContactID and FormTypeID utilizing related tables that are not shown below.  This is a list of FormTypes that each Contact should have related to it as a Form.

I need a query that returns Contacts that do not have one or more related forms of the FormTypes specified in the above query.

I've tried a left outer join from Form to ContactsFormTypesRequired on FormTypeID, but the results don't take into account FormTypes that each specific Contact should have.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

[image: schema]

Comment: Please post the query you tried.

Comment: I'm grateful for everyone's contributions.  ContactFormTypesRequired is basically a query that goes from Contact join to ContactType join to m2m ContactTypeFormType to FormType.  If I had stated that in the first place, would you go about finding Contacts missing specified form Types using ContactFormTypesRequired and your answer below.  OR is there a better way?  Forgive me for not giving that detail in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created ContactFormTypeExist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contact.ContactID, Form.FormTypeID
FROM Contact 
    INNER JOIN ContactForm 
        ON Contact.ContactID = ContactForm.ContactID 
    INNER JOIN Form 
        ON ContactForm.FormID = Form.FormID
```

Then joined ContactFormTypesRequired described in the question above to ContactFormTypeExist with outer join to give me the ConactIDs that are missing related FormTypeIDs:

```
SELECT ContactFormTypesRequired.ConactID
FROM ContactFormTypeExist 
    RIGHT JOIN ContactFormTypesRequired 
        ON (ContactFormTypeExist.FormTypeID = ContactFormTypesRequired.FormTypeID) 
            AND (ContactFormTypeExist.ConactID = ContactFormTypesRequired.ConactID)
WHERE (((ContactFormTypeExist.ConactID) Is Null));
```

This returns all the ContactID for Contacts missing FormTypes required by their ContactType.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing the query this way.  This first starts with your query to get needed forms as a CTE, then cross joins them to Contacts to get every needed combination, before left joining to the actual forms.

```
with NeededForms (<yourqueryhere>)
select distinct c.*
from Contact c cross join
     NeededForms nf left outer join
     Form F
     on nf.FormTypeId = f.FormTypeId left outer join
     ContactForm cf
     on c.ContactId = cf.ContactId and
        f.FormId = cf.FormId
where cf.FormId is null
```

I'm doing it this way, so you can answer the query of what forms are missing with a very similar query:

```
with NeededForms (<yourqueryhere>)
select c.*, nf.FormTypeId
from Contact c cross join
     NeededForms nf left outer join
     Form F
     on nf.FormTypeId = f.FormTypeId left outer join
     ContactForm cf
     on c.ContactId = cf.ContactId and
        f.FormId = cf.FormId
where cf.FormId is null
```

Comment: ContactFormTypesRequired doesn't return FormID, it returns FormTypeID.  For example a Form Type might be application.  It may be possible for a contact to have multiple instances of an application each of which would be represented by a FormID.  Would I just use FormTypeID in place of FormID in your query to find Contacts whose ContactType requires them to have an Application, but they don't have one?

Comment: I revised the query based on the improved description of the data model.

Comment: Did you intend to relate NeededForms to Forms on FormID = FormTypeID? This won't work as it is, nevertheless, I see how you're approaching it.  I'll give it a shot.  Thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've been trying your second query above, but I'm having a hard time matching your aliases with declared tables, queries, etc.  I'm assuming that c is somehow supposed to be referencing Contact and f is somehow referencing Form. Can you please assist?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your swift response to my comment.  When I applied the changes the query returned all the Contacts in the system rather than those missing FormTypeIDs.  I've come up with a combination of queries that work and posted them as an answer.  I am grateful for your interactions on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query using NOT IN Cluase:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
WHERE ContactID IN 
(SELECT ContactID FROM ContactForm 
INNER JOIN FORM ON ContactForm.FormID=Form.FormID
WHERE FormTypeID=@FormTypeID)
```

Comment: This only finds `Contact`s with no `Form` at all. It doesn't find `Contact`s who have at least one `Form` but are missing one or more additional required `FormType`s as found by the view `ContactFormTypesRequired`.

Comment: If you don't have the view `ContactFormTypesRequired` reference in your query, the no matter how many edits you make or how long the query is or how smashing a rowset it produces, it will be *the wrong answer*.

Comment: @ErikE, take it easy, Yes I read again cResults question, I think I misunderstand the question part related to ContactFormTypesRequired , I will write it back again in a new Answer later and delete this after my work day.

Comment: So you think I'm overreacting or freaking out or something?